# jquery.form.min.js loaded after huge delay

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I'm new to Struts2-jquery programming and I ran into a problem i'm not able to solve on my own
I'm upgrading an old Struts2 servlet adding some Jquery functions, the problem is that now the loading time is increased too much. I checked with firebug and it seems that the loding of some js files (related to struts2-jquery plugin) is taking a lot of time even before starting
for example jquery.form.min.js takes about 1/3 of the total time just before its loading process start

Is there any way to speed up the loading of the .js files?

i'm using struts2 2.2.3, struts2-jquery plugin 3.1.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found out that loading the .js from google improves the performance i.e. using (<sj:head loadFromGoogle="true"/>), is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Check out Google Page Speed (http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/). It will give you feedback on what types of things you can do to improve the client-side performance.

Comment: alternatively you can use yslow Mozilla plug-in which also show you various points where page is slow and what can be done to improve that https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look at the sites you are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Upload them to better host, preferably host without cookies